# How to I pass a javascript object back to the server

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-table

I'm working with the wenzhixin bootstrap-table (Because I'm being made to use it).

I have a bunch of search fields so on Post, I package up all of the fields nice and neat to send back to the server.
[image: query params]

[image: Object to pass back]

[image: server side parameters]

But As you can see all of the fields in pageParam are null but PrefixNameID should be 1. Please note that pageNumber, pageSize, and sortOrder are all correct and not null.

Is there something glaringly obvious that I'm doing wrong here?

Edit: Ajax call - this is the authors code

```
request = $.extend({}, calculateObjectValue(null, this.options.ajaxOptions), {
        type: this.options.method,
        url: this.options.url,
        data: this.options.contentType === 'application/json' && this.options.method === 'post' ?
            JSON.stringify(data) : data,
        cache: this.options.cache,
        contentType: this.options.contentType,
        dataType: this.options.dataType,
        success: function (res) {
            res = calculateObjectValue(that.options, that.options.responseHandler, [res], res);

            that.load(res);
            that.trigger('load-success', res);
        },
        error: function (res) {
            that.trigger('load-error', res.status);
        },
        complete: function () {
            if (!silent) {
                that.$loading.hide();
            }
        }
    });
```

Edit 2:

```
JSON.stringify(data): "{"pageSize":10,"pageNumber":1,"sortOrder":"asc","pageParam":{"ID":null,"PrefixNameID":null,"FirstName":null,"MiddleName":null,"LastName":null,"SuffixName":null,"Address1":null,"Address2":null,"City":null,"StateID":null,"Zipcode":null,"EmployeeTypeID":null,"NPI":null}}"
```

Holy Cow, It's null!

Comment: How does the ajax call look like?

Comment: So, any chance on seeing that ajax?

Comment: Could you please post result of JSON.stringify(data)?

Comment: Updated with JSON.stringify(data)

Comment: I don't understand your question. From what you've posted of course it will be null because you assign it to null as per your first image `p.pageParam = {a json definition in which all fields are null}`. Where are you actually assigning `p.pageParam.FirstName="Harry"` etc? If you want these fields to be automagically populated then use an `Ajax.BeginForm` workflow or `knockout.js` etc.

Comment: They are not all null.

Comment: Mainly you need to see what is actually being sent from the client. From the code it is hard to guess what will be the value put into 'data' in the ajax calls. Can you open Chrome (or any browser) developer window and look at network tab to see what data was actually sent in the request body? It is very likely that JSON is not correctly being formed here.

Comment: Can somebody give me an ultra-brief run-down of what parts of the posted code are part of the : Model, View, Controller.